# Convert to 12 format time

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a query for time and display it in a pdf, but it is form to string format i want it to convert it to 12 format time.

This is my codes `{nl2br($schedule->cattime)}`

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you show the output for `dd($schedule->cattime)`?

Comment: 10.00
8.30
7.30
8.00
8.30
12.00
13.00
14.00
15.00
16.00
17.00

Answer (score 0):

laravel is using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) as a date/time layer.

to change time/date format in carbon, you need to use [createFromFormat](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);
```

for example, to get 12h time format:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:ia', '03/10/2017 20:10');
```

---

to use carbon from your blade template directly , you will need to use the full namespace:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:ia', '03/10/2017 20:10');
```

---

## Update

depending on your comment, you are getting values from database.

it would be easier to fetch formatted time rather than re-format it using [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function

```
selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(concat(TIME_FORMAT(schedule.start_time, "%r")) separat‌​or "\r\n") as cattime')
```

Comment: i have this in my code and its functional {{ date("g:i a", strtotime($schedule->start_time))}} but i have a group concat query of time, when i converting in time it display only one. what i should i do?

Comment: i didn't get that *`but i have a group concat query of time, when i converting in time it display only one.`* ? please clarify this to me;

Comment: this is my query
->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(concat(schedule.start_time)separator "\r\n") as cattime')

{!! date("g:i a", strtotime(nl2br($schedule->cattime)))!!} and this is on my blade.

it gives me only 12 AM when im trying to convert all this time 10.00 8.30 7.30 8.00 8.30 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'separat‌​or "\r\n") as cattime

Comment: leave a space between the group function and separat‌​or, check the updated query

Comment: sir im trying to add field but it is error selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(concat(TIME_FORMAT(schedule.start_time,schedule.end_time, "%r"))separator "\r\n") as cattime')

Comment: inside your controller or model , use the following: `->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(concat(TIME_FORMAT(schedule.start_time, "%r")) separat‌​or "\r\n") as cattime')`

Comment: sir i add a field of schedule.end_time and it is error

Comment: sir i got it but, it gives me all 12:00:01 AM

Comment: replace this `%r` by the following : `%l:%i %p` .

Comment: to customize your [time format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: it the same sir, i think it is on my data type. my data type is varchar, and e.g 13.00 that is my time and i want it sir to convert in hour. can i have that one sir?

Comment: 10.00-11.00
8.30-9.30
7.30-8.30
8.00-9.00
8.30-9.30
12.00-13.00
13.00-14.00
14.00-15.00
15.00-16.00
16.00-17.00
17.00-18.00
how i convert this in a 12 hour format.